# Why can't I open the console in Oblivion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I used to play Oblivion on my old HP Laptop and the console commands worked fine, but since I brought my new computer, suddenly the console doesn't open when I press the tilde key. (Next to the 1 key.) I have an MSI AE 2020 touchscreen computer with NVIDIA ION. My keyboard is a MSI StarTypeES500.

Comment: You probably just haven't enabled the console in your new install http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Console

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have set `bAllowConsole` to `1` in your `oblivion.ini` file.

It's likely you had this set on your old PC and not on the new one.

Comment: Additionaly: Check if disabling any infrared receiver in the Device Manager helps. Seriously - Oblivion has problems with that specific kind of HID, and Bethesda as usual never bothered to patch it ...

Answer (score 4):

There is a known issue with Microsoft eHome Infrared Transceiver - If the other methods don't work, then uninstall this:

- Go to your Control Panel,
- Click *System and Security*, -> System,
- Go to *Manage Devices*, and find & click on Human Interface Devices
- Once in there find a file called "Microsoft eHome Infrared Transceiver" and uninstall it (My info came from here: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/959559-/56821937)

Comment: How, exactly, does a completely unrelated system affect what you can or can't do in Oblivion?

Comment: "Thank you so much. Now I can mess around all I want and try to kill every last living thing on the wasteland." –OP of the GameFAQs question. How or why it works is a SU question.

Comment: @Frank Seems to be an unresolved issue, see http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Console. (General Info / Note at bottom)

Comment: Had this issue on Windows 7 -- solved with this answer. Thank you.